# Magento 1.9.1.0 - TypeError: this.toggleElements.toggleSingle is not a function

Tags: magento-1.9

After installed Bannerslider.

Error: Uncaught TypeError: this.toggleElements.toggleSingle is not a function

app.js:1004

```
enquire.register('(max-width: ' + bp.medium + 'px)', {
    setup: function () {
        this.toggleElements = $j(
            // This selects the menu on the My Account and CMS pages
            '.col-left-first .block:not(.block-layered-nav) .block-title, ' +
                '.col-left-first .block-layered-nav .block-subtitle--filter, ' +
                '.sidebar:not(.col-left-first) .block .block-title'
        );
    },
    match: function () {
        this.toggleElements.toggleSingle();
    },
    unmatch: function () {
        this.toggleElements.toggleSingle({destruct: true});
    }
});
```

Comment: I resolved the error:
Added noconflict.js after jquery of bannerslider.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69409/magento-1-9-typeerror-this-toggleelements-togglesingle-is-not-a-function