# Magento Product More Views Not working in Responsive Mobile Theme

Tags: product-images, magento-1.9.3.2

I am using magento 1.9.3.2. In Product Detail page, more views working fine in website view. But Not working in Responsive Mobile Theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got error in console `TypeError: this.toggleElements.toggleSingle is not a function`.

This [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69409/magento-1-9-typeerror-this-toggleelements-togglesingle-is-not-a-function) solved my problem. Thanks @Jelle Siderius.

Change Code in app.js as follows:

```
 match: function () {
    if(this.toggleElements.length > 0){
        this.toggleElements.toggleSingle();
    }
},
unmatch: function () {
    if(this.toggleElements.length > 0){
        this.toggleElements.toggleSingle({destruct: true});
    }
}
```